# Visual Studio Test Task: Test Assembly wildcard format

Tags: c#

I have a library with core functionalities ("Base.dll") with attached unit test projects ("Base.Test.dll") which have a separate build definition. I have projects which depend on these core functionalities ("SomeTool.dll") also with attached unit tests ("SomeTool.Test.dll").

Moreover I have a special unit test project ("Base.Test.Structure.dll") which checks for all *.csproj files it finds in the parent directory of the directory where the binaries get compiled to if they are configured the right way e.g. `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`.

Having gated check-ins activated and having a Base build definition in place it is not necessary to run Base.Test in every build of every tool. I therefore wanted to adapt the default pattern in the field "Test Assembly" of the Visual Studio Test Task from

```
**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*.test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
```

to

```
**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*.test*.dll;-:**\obj\**;-:**\Base.*;+:**\Base.Test.Structure.dll
```

however the structure tests do not get discovered and are not executed. In a tool's build definition with no tool specific unit test I get "No results found to publish.".

I suspect it is not possible to use a "+:" after a "-:" in the pattern. Can someone confirm this? Is there another way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: According to https://blogs.infosupport.com/tfs2015-build-tasks-the-wildcard-format-explained/ `All exclusion expressions always take precedence over the inclusion expressions, so if a file matches both an inclusion and an exclusion expression, the file is not included.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Test task is just using the **Visual Studio Test runner**. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test.

> Test Assembly:  This field specifies the test assemblies(s) from which
>   the tests should be picked.
>
> - Wildcards can be used
> - Multiple paths can be specified separated by a semicolon
> - Paths are relative to the Sources Directory
>
> For example, `**\commontests\*test*.dll;
>   **\frontendtests\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**` or `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Tests\*tests*.dll;-:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Tests\Integrationtests.dll`
>
> Include patterns start with ‘`+`:’, and exclude patterns with ‘`-`:’
>   (Default is include). For Javascript tests, this will point to .js
>   files containing the tests. Folders/Files which are having ";" in
>   their names should be given as ";;" in input.
>
> *[Run Tests using Visual Studio task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/releases/m109/Tasks/VsTest/README.md)*

The doc is not declared you could not possible to use a "+:" after a "-:" in the pattern.

The comment of the blog is right, All exclusion expressions always take precedence over the inclusion expressions, so if a file matches both an inclusion and an exclusion expression, the file is not included.

For newly version of [vststest task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTestV2/README.md), it's change `-` to `!`. The official doc about [minimatch patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/vsts/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=vsts) also declared clearly:

> leading ! changes the meaning of an include pattern to exclude.
>
> ***[Exclude patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/vsts/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=vsts)***